# Downloaded PyCharm and now Java is broken in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, sdk, pycharm

Like the title says, I downloaded Pycharm and now my Java project in Intellij is broken. IntelliJ was totally fine beforehand. I know have errors in every file in random places. I also had errors on java imports such as "import java.util.List", (resolved now, see below).

In IntelliJ, I went to File > Project Structure and saw that the SDK was set to Python 3. I changed that JDK 1.8 that I already had set up. That resolved the import errors but I now have weird methods that can't resolve such as concat() or orElse().

Any ideas??

Comment: Try using JDK11.

Comment: @CrazyCoder hi thanks I wish I could try this but this is a work project so I have to stick to 8

Comment: Please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you opened the same project in PyCharm and IDEA?

Answer (score -1):

To fix this, I had to right click on the pom file and click "add as maven project"